# Node JS - Stream data from Busboy to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, busboy

I am trying to upload a file to s3 via ec2.
My first approach was - upload file to ec2 completely and then upload that file to s3. This approach is not good because transfer time from ec2 to s3 is waste of time.

Currently I am trying to use **busboy upload stream** to **s3 upload stream** so that uploading to ec2 and then ec2 to s3 will be done simultaneously as s3 **"upload"** method support stream as upload Body.

Here is my code -

```
router.post('/s3StreamUpload', function(req, res, next) {
   var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
   busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('Before Upload: ' + new Date());
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);

      var s3 = new AWS.S3({
         params: {Bucket: 'sswa', Key: filename, Body: file},
         options: {partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 10}   // 5 MB
      });
      s3.upload().on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
         console.log(evt);
      }).send(function (err, data) {
         console.log('After Upload: ' + new Date());
         console.log(err, data);
      });
   });
   busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
   });
   busboy.on('finish', function() {
      console.log('Done parsing form!');
      res.writeHead(303, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
      res.end();
   });
   req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

I have doubt is it really uploading to s3 simultaneously as stream ? Is there any drawbacks of this approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test whether multi-part streaming upload to S3 is working or not, I took time log at three points of execution -

1. Before start upload from client (**uploadStartTime**)
2. After uploaded to EC2 (**busboyFinishTime**)
3. After transferred to S3 (**s3UploadFinishTime**)

Then I run from EC2. After uploading various length of video files (36.1 MB, 33.3 MB, 52.5 MB) I observed that parts are transferred to S3 immediately for each 5MB (as I defined) uploaded to EC2. When uploading parts to S3 you will see a log of the following line. It will show file part upload progress with the part number.

```
console.log(evt);
```

For all three uploads **busboyFinishTime** and **s3UploadFinishTime** are same or there is hardly a 1-second difference.

Example:
When 52.5 MB uploaded

```
{
  "uploadStartTime": "2016-04-28T14:19:51.365Z",
  "busboyFinishTime": "2016-04-28T14:22:26.292Z",
  "s3UploadFinishTime": "2016-04-28T14:22:26.558Z"
}
```

Full code:

```
router.post('/s3StreamUpload', function(req, res, next) {
   var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
   var uploadStartTime = new Date(),
      busboyFinishTime = null,
      s3UploadFinishTime = null;

   busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);

      var s3 = new AWS.S3({
         params: {Bucket: 'sswa', Key: filename, Body: file},
         options: {partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 10}   // 5 MB
      });
      s3.upload().on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
         console.log(evt);
      }).send(function (err, data) {
         s3UploadFinishTime = new Date();
         if(busboyFinishTime && s3UploadFinishTime) {
            res.json({
               uploadStartTime: uploadStartTime,
               busboyFinishTime: busboyFinishTime,
               s3UploadFinishTime: s3UploadFinishTime
            });
         }
         console.log(err, data);
      });
   });
   busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) {
      console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
   });
   busboy.on('finish', function() {
      console.log('Done parsing form!');
      busboyFinishTime = new Date();
      if(busboyFinishTime && s3UploadFinishTime) {
         res.json({
            uploadStartTime: uploadStartTime,
            busboyFinishTime: busboyFinishTime,
            s3UploadFinishTime: s3UploadFinishTime
         });
      }
   });
   req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

According to my observations, I feel confident that this is one of the best solutions to upload a file to S3 via EC2 using a REST API deployed on EC2.

Comment: I have tried this approach but the image in S3 is corrupt, even when I set correct ContentType and ContentEncoding. AWS SDK version is 2.184.0. Any ideas?

Comment: @woss, in where you put ContentType and ContentEncoding. In my code, there is nothing like those.

Comment: @mahbub.kuetI believe in the s3.upload as per docs. I went other approach and used multer which is built on busboy.

Comment: @woss, Is your issue fixed now?

Comment: well, it is, as i said i switched to other way of doing it :)

Comment: @woss, As you said you used multer, I have a query. Using multer did you able to stream currently uploading content (user to EC2 instance) to S3 in real time. So far I remember I tried multer to do this. But multer upload whole content from user to EC2 instance and then when entire content saved in EC2, it starts uploading to S3.

Comment: Do you have similar solution to Lambda functions? I tried your solution but having trouble with busboy

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to upload to S3 directly from browser? If so you can use presigned-put for direct browser to S3 uploads.

This is how you generate a presigned PUT url using [minio-js](https://github.com/minio/minio-js)

```
s3Client.presignedPutObject('my-bucketname', 'my-objectname', 1000, function(e, presignedUrl) {
  if (e) return console.log(e)
  console.log(presignedUrl)
})
```

Now you pass this presigned URL to the browser client which can use XMLHttpRequest to directly PUT a file to S3.

Comment: this is a good alternative, but it has nothing to do with what the question is asking

Comment: But this way (uploading from the browser) everyone will see the secret-key credential. Am I right?