# Some trouble uploading image via lambda to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, busboy

I'm creating a image uploader storing to s3 via lambda.

I successed to upload the file but there are difference with original.

How could I upload file same with original?

html

```
  ...
  <form action="https://.../lambdaUploadImageEndPoint" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  ...
```

lambda

```
...
module.exports.uploadImage = function(event, context, callback) {
  const busboy = new Busboy({headers: {'content-type': getContentType(event),}})
  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    s3.upload({
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: filename,
      Body: file,
      ContentType: mimetype
    }, (err, data) => {...})
...
})
```

compare

```
$ cmp test-original.jpg test.jpg
test-original.jpg test.jpg differ: char 1, line 1
```

Comment: What is `file`, as in `Body: file`? Where/how does it get set? (Sorry, I'm not familiar with busboy.) See also: [Node JS - Stream data from Busboy to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911100/node-js-stream-data-from-busboy-to-aws-s3)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. `file` is `FileStream` set by busboy. I tried to set option as the reference but it doesn't resolve the problem:(